# how to optimize this random playlist html5 audio script

Tags: html, audio, random, playlist

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function random_playlist(){
    var myrandom=Math.round(Math.random()*4);
    var soundurl='http://dummy.xy/dummy.mp3';

    if      (myrandom==0){soundurl='http://path_to.mp3';}
    else if (myrandom==1){soundurl='http://path_to.mp3';}
    else if (myrandom==2){soundurl='http://path_to.mp3';}
    else if (myrandom==3){soundurl='http://path_to.mp3';}
    else if (myrandom==4){soundurl='http://path_to.mp3';}
    console.log(soundurl);
    return soundurl;
    };
</script>

<audio id="audioplayer_id" controls="controls" loop>
<source id="source_id" src="" type="audio/mp3"/>
Your browser does not support the audio element
</audio>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var audioload = random_playlist();
    console.log(audioload);
    document.getElementById('source_id').src= audioload;
    var audioplayer_id = document.getElementById('audioplayer_id')
      audioplayer_id.volume = 0.15;
      audioplayer_id.load(); 
      audioplayer_id.play();
</script>
```

Works well for me but can it be optimized or is this OK ?

I just hacked this together from various sources seems like html5 didnt integrate a playlist function in the audio tag, which seems funny to me.
greets

Answer (score 0):

You could shorted the `random_playlist` function like this:

```
function random_playlist(){
    var PATHS = ['http://path_to.mp3', 'http://path_to.mp3', 'http://path_to.mp3'];
    return PATHS[Math.floor(Math.random() * PATHS.length)];
}
```

or (a better but more complicated version):

```
var random_playlist = (function(){
        var PATHS = ['http://path_to.mp3', 'http://path_to.mp3', 'http://path_to.mp3'];
        return function(){
                return PATHS[Math.floor(Math.random() * PATHS.length)]
        };
}())
```